# Does building the compiler from source result in better optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

Consider this simple case scenario:

I download the pre-built binaries of a C++ compiler (say `CLang` or `GCC` or anything else) for my generic OS (that is not windows). I compile my code which consists of some computationally expensive mathematical calculation with optimization flag `-O3` and I have an execution time of `T1`.

On a different attempt, this time instead of using pre-built binaries I download the source code and build the compiler by myself on my generic machine. I compile the same code with the same optimization flag, achieving execution time `T2`?

Will `T2 < T1` or they will be more or less the same?

In other words, is the execution time independent from the way that compiler is built?

Comment: Do you suspect that the pre-built binaries were built in such a way as to leave out some optimizations it could do? If so, why?

Comment: I would only expect the compile time to change.

Comment: @Wooble, exactly! I was/am using GCC and my colleagues in the other laboratory are CLang users. What we do is similar in nature, however, not exactly the same. They told they have had better results with clang, however, when I switched to clang I realized my GCC is still better. When asking them, they all said that they have compiled the clang while I used the pre-built. I just wanted to know if this is relevant.

Comment: It would be great to know the reason for down-votes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler's optimization of your code is the result of the *behavior* of the compiler, not the *performance* of the compiler.

As long as the compiler has the same behavioral design, it will produce exactly the same output.

Comment: Going even further, if all compilation settings and the environment is the same, not only will the output of the compiler be the same, the resulting compiler binaries will also be the exact same as the pre-built ones (maybe apart from timestamps, if any).

Comment: This no attack, I'm just trying to clarify everything before accepting the answer. What you say is that there are *no* attributes of the compiler that are taken from the machine (that compiler is built on) and can affect the execution time. Is this statement true?

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but super unlikely. From what I can tell, I'd say your difference is just because you're testing on different machines.

Comment: Excelsius is right, and IIRC GCC in fact uses this property in its bootstrap install procedure. It compiles **itself** two times, with and without optimization, and checks if the two builds produce the same results. (The optimized GCC should produce the same results in less time)

Answer (score 2):

Generally the same compiler version should generate the same assembler code given the same C or C++ code input. However there are certain things that might further affect the code that is being execute when you run the compiler.

- A distro might have backported (or even created own) patches from other versions.
- Modern compilers often have library depenencies (e.g. cloog) that may have different behaviour in different versions, causing the compiler to make code generation decisions based on essentially other data
- These libraries may (in some compiler versions) be optional at compile time (might need to give --enable switches to configure, or configure tries to autodetect them).
- Compiler switches like `-march=native` will look on what hardware you compile and try to optimize accordingly.
- a time limit in the compilers optimizer triggers, essentially making better optimizations on better machines; or the same for memory (I don't think thats to be found in modern compilers anymore though)

That said, even the same assembler might perform different on yours and their machine, e.g. because one is optimized for AMD, the other for intel.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, and in theory, compilation speed can be faster, since you can say to "compiler which compile the compiler", "please target to my computer, and you can use my computer's processor's own machine code to optimize".

But I think *compiler's optimization* cannot be faster.. To make compiler's optimization faster, I think we need put something like new technology into compiler, not just re-compile.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how that compiler is implemented and on your platform, but the answer will be most likely "no".

**If** your platform provides specific functionality that can improve the performance of your program, the optimizer in your compiler **might** use that functionality to produce a faster program. The optimizer can do so only if the compiler writer was aware of the functionality and has implemented special treatment for your platform in the optimizer. **If** that is the case, the detection might be done dynamically in the optimizer, meaning any build of the optimizer can detect the platform and optimize your code. Only **if** the detection has to occur at compiletime of the optimizer for some reason, recompiling it on your platform could give that advantage. But **if** such a better build for your plaform exists, the compiler vendor most likely has provided binaries for it.

So, with all these ifs, it's unlikely that *your* program will be any faster when you recompile the compiler on your platform. There is a chance, however, that the compiler will be a bit faster if it is optimized to your platform rather than a generic binary, resulting on shorter compiletimes.